# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm just a newbie to programming and have just tried Vue for few days.

Here I would like to store user's geolocation data to Vuex state by the following code.

```
    mounted () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation)
    function foundLocation (position) {
      var userLoc = {
        Lon: position.coords.longitude,
        Lat: position.coords.latitude
      }
      console.log(userLoc)
      this.$store.dispatch('userLocSave', {lat: userLoc.Lat, lon: userLoc.Lon})
    }
    function noLocation () {
      console.log('No Location found!')
    }
  }
```

and here's code in store.js
**State**

```
  state: {
    userLat: null,
    userLon: null
  }
```

**Mutation**

```
userLocation (state, locData) {
  state.userLat = locData.lat
  state.userLon = locData.lon
}
```

**Action**

```
userLocSave ({commit}, locData) {
  commit('userLocation', {
    lat: locData.lat,
    lon: locData.lon
  })
}
```

However, it doesn't work as I thought and shows this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of null
at foundLocation
```

I have tried to search, but have no idea what keywords, and I have been stuck with this problem for a day already. So, I decided to ask here. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue with scope:

`this` in the context your using it is scoped to your `function()` not the vue instance.

One way to sort this would be to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Arrow functions maintain the scope of the caller so in this instance, `this` will still be scoped to the vue instance.

```
mounted () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    () => {
        var userLoc = {
            Lon: position.coords.longitude,
            Lat: position.coords.latitude
        }
        console.log(userLoc)
        this.$store.dispatch('userLocSave', {lat: userLoc.Lat, lon: userLoc.Lon})
    }, 
    () => { 
        console.log('No Location found!')
    })
}
```

Comment: Not  a problem, I find myself using arrow function a lot in Vue. Just be warned, you can't use them to declare computed functions as the scope won't be set correctly.