# Change Vuex state with Vuetify Switch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I am making a multi-component Vue app with Vuetify and have implemented a Settings page (Settings.vue) and have a `v-switch` for theme settings to change the app to dark mode. I can get the initial state for the switch by using `v-model="this.$store.state.isDark"` but when I use click it I set it to run a method `@change="changeDark()"`.

`methods`

```
methods: {
    changeDark: () => this.$store.dispatch("commitDarkMode")
}
```

I get this error in console

`Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of null"`

`Cannot read property '$store' of null`

I've read that it's because their switch wasn't wrapped in a `v-app` but mine is, here's my App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app :dark="this.$store.state.isDark">
    <Header />
    <router-view />
  </v-app>
</template>
```

And my Settings.vue

```
<template>
    <v-main>
        <v-container fluid>
            <v-row>
                <v-col cols="4">
                    <v-card>
                        <v-card-title> Worlds - {{this.$store.state.worldsList.length}} </v-card-title>
                        <v-card-subtitle> List of total saved worlds </v-card-subtitle>
                        <v-divider></v-divider>
                        <v-list>
                            <v-list-item v-for="(n, index) in this.$store.state.worldsList" :key="n + index">
                                <v-card flat fluid>
                                    <v-card-title> {{n.name}} </v-card-title>
                                    <v-card-subtitle> {{n.desc}} </v-card-subtitle>
                                </v-card>
                            </v-list-item>
                        </v-list>
                    </v-card>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="6">
                   <v-card>
                       <v-card-title>Theme Settings</v-card-title>
                       <v-divider></v-divider>
                       <v-switch v-model="this.$store.state.isDark" :label="`Dark Mode`" @change="changeDark()"></v-switch>
                       <v-card-subtitle> <b> More Coming Soon </b> </v-card-subtitle>
                   </v-card>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="2">
                    <v-card>
                        <b> More Coming Soon </b>
                    </v-card>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-row></v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-main>
</template>
```

And my Vue instance structure via the Vue chrome extension
[image]

I'm assuming this is because it can;t access the Vue instance, as `this` isn't working but why?

EDIT:
Using a `v-btn` works perfectly fine, just seems the switch isn't working. I have also tried a `v-checkbox` and it doesn't work either

Comment: This is due to your using `this` inside an arrow function in your method.

Comment: I've tried it without and it still doesn't work. Doing this `changeDark: function() { this.$store.dispatch("commitDarkMode") }` still doesn't work

Comment: Now that's interesting, using the declared function like that still gives you the same error?

Comment: For reference, this is what I thought your issue was: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48472445/11047824

Comment: yes it gives the same error, I also checked out that thread and seemed no help

Comment: [Carlos Abreu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3938726) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66253865) saying "did you exported the state of your store?,
the actions, the state and the mutations ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mapActions worked just fine, however I believe the problem wasn't with dispatching but rather setting the original value, as when I changed this it fixed.

This:
`<v-switch v-model="this.$store.state.isDark" :label="Dark Mode" @change="changeDark()"></v-switch>`

To
`<v-checkbox v-model="darkMode" :label="Dark Mode" @change="changeDark()"></v-checkbox>`

Answer (score 0):

```
changeDark() {
 this.$store.dispatch("commitDarkMode")
 }
```